# Skip over iteration in Enumerable#collect

Tags: ruby, enumerable

```
(1..4).collect do |x|
  next if x == 3
  x + 1
end # => [2, 3, nil, 5]
    # desired => [2, 3, 5]
```

If the condition for `next` is met, `collect` puts `nil` in the array, whereas what I'm trying to do is put *no* element in the returned array if the condition is met. Is this possible without calling `delete_if { |x| x == nil }` on the returned array?

My code excerpt is heavily abstracted, so looking for a general solution to the problem.

Comment: There's a real quick, built to purpose solution to this introduced in 2.7: `filter_map`, [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152098/skip-over-iteration-in-enumerablecollect/57323739#answer-57323739).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby 2.7+, it’s possible to use [`filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) for this exact purpose. From [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map):

> Returns an array containing truthy elements returned by the block.
>
> ```
> (0..9).filter_map {|i| i * 2 if i.even? }   #=> [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]
> {foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 2}.filter_map {|key, value| key if value.even? }  #=> [:foo, :baz]
> ```

For the example in the question: `(1..4).filter_map { |x| x + 1 unless x == 3 }`.

See [this post](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/05/25/ruby-2-7-enumerable-filter-map.html) for comparison with alternative methods, including benchmarks.

Comment: Great find :) It also works with `next` as tried by the OP: 

`numbers.filter_map { |i| next if i.odd?; i * 2 }`

Answer (score 80):

There is method [`Enumerable#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) which serves just the purpose:

```
(1..4).reject{|x| x == 3}.collect{|x| x + 1}
```

The practice of directly using an output of one method as an input of another is called *method chaining* and is very common in Ruby.

BTW, `map` (or `collect`) is used for direct mapping of input enumerable to the output one. If you need to output different number of elements, chances are that you need another method of `Enumerable`.

Edit: If you are bothered by the fact that some of the elements are iterated twice, you can use less elegant solution based on `inject` (or its similar method named [`each_with_object`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)):

```
(1..4).each_with_object([]){|x,a| a << x + 1 unless x == 3}
```

Comment: This is the slowest answer (not by much though), but is certainly the cleanest. I just wish there was a way to do this with `collect`, as I would've expected calling `next` to have returned _absolutely nothing_, rather than "nothing" (aka `nil`).

Comment: If it's slower than any other approach, Ruby's optimizer could use some work don't you think?

Answer (score 49):

I would simply call `.compact` on the resultant array, which removes any instances of nil in an array.  If you'd like it to modify the existing array (no reason not to), use `.compact!`:

```
(1..4).collect do |x|
  next if x == 3
  x
end.compact!
```

Comment: I did a quick benchmark, for interest, of the four solutions suggested so far: collect+compact, collect+compact!, reject+collect and building a results array as you go. In MRI 1.9.1, at least, collect+compact! is the speed winner by a narrow margin, with collect+compact and reject+collect pretty close behind. Building the results array is about twice as slow as those.

Comment: @glenn: Would you mind including the following to your benchmark: `(1..4).inject([]){|a,x| x == 3 ? a : a.push(x + 1)}`? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. That's the slowest one yet, albeit only slightly slower than building the results array. I also added a version tweaked like this: `a.inject([]){|aa,x| aa << x + 1 unless x == 3; aa}`, which was faster than building the array, but still considerably slower than the three 3 fast ways.

Comment: This would work, but you'd have to worry about cases where the original array had legitimate `nil`s in them.

Comment: @Andrew G. That's true, though in my particular case that would never happen. Good side-effect worth noting though.

Comment: I dunno about using `map{}.compact!`, b/c it returns `nil` if nothing was skipped. I guess if you can be guaranteed that at least one element will be skipped...

Comment: You should consider performance before using this. I think it's better just use `each` instead of these fancy magic

Comment: I like this solution, but the `next` is misleading because it's not really skipping the collect, it's just stopping the execution of the block and adding nil to the array.  You could write it more clearly and cleanly like this: `(1..4).collect { |x| x + 1 unless x == 3 }.compact` or even better and more clear in my mind: `(1..4).select {|n| n != 3}.map {|x| x + 1}`

Answer (score 4):

just a suggestion, why don't you do it this way:

```
result = []
(1..4).each do |x|
  next if x == 3
  result << x
end
result # => [1, 2, 4]
```

in that way you saved another iteration to remove nil elements from the array. hope it helps =)

Comment: This is like a much more verbose version of Mladen's `reject` example.

Comment: actually nope, "reject" iterates through the array once, and "collect" iterates through the array once again, so there's two iterations. in the case of "each" it does so only once =)

Comment: This is a reasonable idea, but in Ruby it's often very interesting to do the speed test and see what actually happens. In my quick benchmark (which might or might not match Andrew's real case, of course), building the array this way is actually about twice as slow as any of the other ways. I suspect the issue is that iterating through the array in C is actually a lot faster than appending items at the Ruby << level.

Comment: This is using mutable state, rather than a functional programming style.

Comment: There's actually no need for `next` here. Simply `result << x unless x == 3` would work and is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Staelen I apologize, you are correct. That said, I still think the prettier and faster solutions win this round.

Comment: @benson: no worries benson =)
@andrew: yeah u r right, 1 vote up =)

Comment: @Staelen Ideally the interpreter would optimize it down to a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use:

```
(1..4).to_a.delete_if {|x| x == 3}
```

instead of the collect + next statement.

Comment: The _real_ code is more complicated than the abstracted code in my question, so this wouldn't achieve what I'm looking for, unfortunately. (The collect actually manipulates the value, rather than just returning it)

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the decision-making into a helper method, and use it via [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
def potentially_keep(list, i)
  if i === 3
    list
  else
    list.push i
  end
end
# => :potentially_keep

(1..4).reduce([]) { |memo, i| potentially_keep(memo, i) }
# => [1, 2, 4]
```