# Mapping and selecting at the same time

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, enumerable, ruby-1.9.3

Is there a good way to `map` and (`select` or `delete_if`) at the same time? At the moment, I do either of the following, but was wondering if there is a better way. Also, I cannot use the second one if I want a falsy value within the resulting array.

```
some_array.select{|x| some_condition(x)}.map{|x| modification(x)}

some_array.map{|x| modification(x) if some_condition(x)}.compact
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152098/skip-over-iteration-in-enumerablecollect but no good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby, is there an Array method that combines 'select' and 'map'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371518/in-ruby-is-there-an-array-method-that-combines-select-and-map) - which has a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the same to reduce or inject

```
new_array = some_array.each_with_object([]) do |m,res|
  res << modification(x) if some_condition(x)
end
```

The difference is that you don't need to put result at the end of block.

Comment: Didn't know each_with_object. Neat!

Comment: Check it here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_objectvvvvvv

Comment: In `rails console` it works but not in `irb`. OP is asking about pure ruby. Are you sure this method exists in pure ruby for arrays? It does for hashes.

Comment: I've sent you a link to pure ruby, but i edited it several times, so please check it again.

Comment: BTW, i didn't undo your answer

Comment: Edit your answer so I can give you your vote back but this does **not** work for me using pure ruby 1.9. BTW I did check this before downvoting. Didn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9165/discussion-between-megas-and-kyle)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
new_array = some_array.inject([]) do |arr, x|
  some_condition(x) ? arr << modification(x) : arr
end
```

Anytime I think about mapping then selecting or mapping then rejecting etc..., it usually means I can use an [enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) to get the job done.