# How to omit empty rows using last_row in Roo Rails

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-5, roo

I have a spreadsheet of `members` designed as below:
[image]

My aim is to upload some columns and exclude others. In this case, I wish to upload only the `name`, `age` and `email` and exclude the others. I have been able to achieve this using the `slice` method as shown below:

```
def load_imported_members
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
    spreadsheet.default_sheet = 'Worksheet'
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      member = Member.find_by_id(row["id"]) || Member.new
      member.attributes = row.to_hash.slice("id", "name", "age", "email")
      member
    end
  end
```

The problem is that `last_row` considers all the rows upto the last one (13), and since there are validations on the form, there are errors due to missing data as a result of the empty rows (which shouldn’t be considered). Is there a way I can upload only specific columns as I have done, yet limit to only the rows that have data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to chain the `map` call off of a `reject` filter like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152098/skip-over-iteration-in-enumerablecollect#5152432)

You may just need to change the `map` line to this (assuming the missing rows all look like those above):
`(2..spreadsheet.last_row).reject{|i| spreadsheet.row(i)[0] }.map do |i|`

This is assuming the blank rows return as nil and that blank rows will always have all four desired fields blank as shown in the image.  The `reject` call tests to see if `spreadsheet.row(i)[0]`, the id column, is nil, if so the item is rejected from the list output given to `map`

Comment: Thanks @randall-coding, however, it is still not rejecting the blank rows ;-(

Comment: Any ideas? Still not been able to crack it. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question. I have learned some things from this question.

I have shortlisted your answer [note: use 'ROO' gem]

```
def load_imported_members(member)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(member)
  spreadsheet.each do |records|
  record = @spreadsheet ? Hash[[@header, @spreadsheet.row(records)].transpose] : Hash[records] # transpose for xlsx records and 
  attributes =  {id: record['id'], name: record['name'], email: record['email'], age: record['age']}
  member_object = Member.new(attributes)
  if member_object.valid?
    if Member.find(attributes[:id])
      Member.find(attributes[:id]).update(attributes)
    else
      member_object.save
    end
  end
 end
end
```

You can parse your uploaded file using **Roo** gem.

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(member)
case File.extname(member.file.original_filename)
when ".csv" then
  Roo::CSV.new(member.file.expiring_url, csv_options: {headers: true, skip_blanks: true, header_converters: ->(header) { header.strip }, converters: ->(data) { data ? data.strip : nil }})
when ".xlsx", ".xls" then
  @spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(member.file.expiring_url)
  @header = @spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..@spreadsheet.last_row)
 end
end
```

Here I have used s3 uploaded url i.e expiring_url. Hope This will helpful. I have not tested. sorry, for small errors.

If you have used validations for name, email, and age. This will surely help u..

Comment: Thank you @rajkumar for your answer. Does your answer factor in the header row? Sorry I am beginner but I see your logic

Comment: Nope. Here we won't worry about headers bcoz we mentioned  as headers to true.

Comment: Thanks @rajkumar  and I feel am getting there. What If I want to import from Excel (xlsx)..how will the parsing be done?

Comment: I have updated for xlsx. That will be helping @adamvanbart