# Upload excel data using a combination of two columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, roo-gem

I have an excel sheet which has the format shown below:
[image]

Members can have multiple entries in the corresponding `members` table. When uploading data from the excel template, I would like to `find_by` `pin` as well as `end_date` so that I update the specific record during upload.

I am using `gem roo` to import excel data, and here is my `load_imported_members` method:

```
def load_imported_members
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
    spreadsheet.default_sheet = 'Worksheet'
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      member = Member.find_by_pin(row["pin"]) || Member.new
      member.attributes = row.to_hash.slice("id", "name", "pin", "end_date", "email")
      member
    end
  end
```

I reckon that if I use both `pin` and `end_date` in the `find_by` method, I will update the specific record, since there could be two entries in the table, but one must have an `end_date`. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find just one record at a time you can use a `find_by()` with a hash to search with multiple columns like this:

`Member.find_by(pin:row["pin"],end_date: row["end_date"])`

`find_by` is explained more [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

If you want to retrieve multiple records matching your search you need the `where()` function on the Member class instead of `find_by()`

`where` is explained more [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Comment: Could you help out with an almost similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517282/how-to-omit-empty-rows-using-last-row-in-roo-rails @randall-coding? Thank you