# Arrays: conditionally mapping elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I work with Redux and it often happens to me to write reducers with expressions like this one:

```
return users.map(user =>
  user.id !== selectedUserID ? user : {
    ... user,
    removed: false
  }
);
```

The intent should be clear enough: **modify just the item in the array that has the given id, while copying the others as they are**. Also note that ordering is important, otherwise I could just have used a `filter()` function.

This snippet triggers a [no-confusing-arrow](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-confusing-arrow) error on eslint, which makes sense to me. This can also be easily solved by adding round parenthesis around the arrow function body, so no big deal here:

```
return users.map(user => (
  user.id !== selectedUserID ? user : {
    ... user,
    removed: false
  }
));
```

I also want to parse this code through [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier), which automatically removes the parenthesis around the arrow function body, going back to version 1 of the snippet.

The obvious solution here is to write the arrow function the verbose way:

```
return users.map(user => {
  if(user.id !== selectedUserID) {
    return user; // unmodified user
  }
  return {
    ... user,
    removed: false
  };
});
```

but I honestly find it a bit too clumsy.

**Aside from the specific context and the used tools** (eslint and prettier, which can be configured differently/turned off/whatever), **is there any better way to write this?**

In my wildest dreams it exists a function with a signature similar to:

```
Array.mapIf(callback, condition)
```

that cycles all the elements in the array, and calls the `callback` function only to the ones satisfying the given `condition`, while returning the other elements unmodified.

*I could obviously write a function like this myself, but maybe there is something already existing in other functional languages that may be worth to look at for general culture/inspiration.*

Comment: I don't think there's such a function in any major language - it's either this or my Google-fu isn't up to scratch. Probably the latter. This function doesn't exist in Clojure, which is a major functional programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such native function because you can easily implement it yourself:

```js
const mapWhen = (p, f) => xs => xs.map(x => p(x) ? f(x) : x);

const users = [
  {id: 1, removed: true},
  {id: 2, removed: true},
  {id: 3, removed: true}
];

console.log(
  mapWhen(
    ({id}) => id === 2,
    user => Object.assign({}, user, {removed: false})
  ) (users)
);
```

I've chosen `mapWhen` as the name instead of `mapIf`, because the latter would imply that there is an `else` branch.

With a mature functional language you would probably solve this issue with a [functional lense](https://github.com/DrBoolean/lenses). I think, however, `mapWhen` is sufficient for your case and more idiomatic.

Comment: Agree with the naming! Any particular reason why you are returning a function accepting an array, instead of directly passing the array as third (or first) parameter function?

Comment: I obviously meant: passing the array as third (or first) parameter *to the* function

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni In FP you usually define curried functions, where each lambda takes a single argument. In JS people are used to multi-argument functions though. So I tend to take this middle ground, where only the last argument corresponds to the curry form, so that the function is composable.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby you would return something like

```
users.dup.select {|u| u.id == selected_user_id }.each {|u| u.removed = false }
```

`dup` is important in this case because in Redux you want to return a new array and not modify the original one, so you first have to create a copy of the original. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/625746/1627766 (notice the discussion is very similar to this one)

In your case I would use:

```js
const users = [
  {id: 1, removed: true},
  {id: 2, removed: true},
  {id: 3, removed: true}
];

const selectedUserId = 2;

console.log(
  users.map(
    (user) => ({
      ...user,
      removed: (user.id !== selectedUserId ? false : user.removed)
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: I like the Ruby way to solve the problem, the select function seems great in cases like this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which add the property if necessary.

```
return users.map(user =>
    Object.assign({}, user, user.id === selectedUserID && { removed: false })
);
```

Comment: I didn't consider this option, could be a decent solution to this specific case, thanks! Still, I'd like to see if there is a more generic way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide this as a supplement to @ftor's practical answer – this snippet shows how generic functions can be used to accomplish kind of result

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const comp = ( f, g ) =>
  x => f ( g ( x ) )
  
const compose = ( ...fs ) =>
  fs.reduce ( comp, identity )
  
const append = ( xs, x ) =>
  xs.concat ( [ x ] )

const transduce = ( ...ts ) => xs =>
  xs.reduce ( compose ( ...ts ) ( append ), [] )

const when = f =>
  k => ( acc, x ) => f ( x ) ? k ( acc, x ) : append ( acc, x )

const mapper = f =>
  k => ( acc, x ) => k ( acc, f ( x ) )

const data0 =
  [ { id: 1, remove: true }
  , { id: 2, remove: true }
  , { id: 3, remove: true }
  ]

const data1 =
  transduce ( when ( x => x.id === 2)
            , mapper ( x => ( { ...x, remove: false } ) )
            )
            (data0)
            
console.log (data1)
// [ { id: 1, remove: true }
// , { id: 2, remove: false }
// , { id: 3, remove: true }
// ]
```

However, I think we could improve `when` with a more generic behavior, all we need is a little help from some invented types `Left` and `Right` – expand complete code snippet after this excerpt

```
const Left = value =>
  ({ fold: ( f, _ ) =>
       f ( value )
  })

const Right = value =>
  ({ fold: ( _, f ) =>
       f ( value )
  })

// a more generic when
const when = f =>
  k => ( acc, x ) => f ( x ) ? k ( acc, Right ( x ) ) : k ( acc, Left ( x ) )

// mapping over Left/Right
mapper ( m =>
  m.fold ( identity                         // Left branch
         , x => ( { ...x, remove: false } ) // Right branch
         ) )
```

```js
const Left = value =>
  ({ fold: ( f, _ ) =>
       f ( value )
  })
  
const Right = value =>
  ({ fold: ( _, f ) =>
       f ( value )
  })

const identity = x =>
  x

const comp = ( f, g ) =>
  x => f ( g ( x ) )
  
const compose = ( ...fs ) =>
  fs.reduce ( comp, identity )
  
const append = ( xs, x ) =>
  xs.concat ( [ x ] )

const transduce = ( ...ts ) => xs =>
  xs.reduce ( compose ( ...ts ) ( append ), [] )

const when = f =>
  k => ( acc, x ) => f ( x ) ? k ( acc, Right ( x ) ) : k ( acc, Left ( x ) )

const mapper = f =>
  k => ( acc, x ) => k ( acc, f ( x ) )

const data0 =
  [ { id: 1, remove: true }
  , { id: 2, remove: true }
  , { id: 3, remove: true }
  ]

const data1 =
  transduce ( when ( x => x.id === 2 )
            , mapper ( m =>
               m.fold ( identity
                      , x => ( { ...x, remove: false } ) 
                      ) )
            )
            (data0)
            
console.log (data1)
// [ { id: 1, remove: true }
// , { id: 2, remove: false }
// , { id: 3, remove: true }
// ]
```

So your final function would probably look something like this

```
const updateWhen = ( f, records, xs ) =>
  transduce ( when ( f )
            , mapper ( m =>
                m.fold ( identity
                       , x => ( { ...x, ...records } )
                       ) )
            ) ( xs )
```

You'll call it in your reducer like this

```
const BakeryReducer = ( donuts = initState , action ) =>
  {
    switch ( action.type ) {
      case ApplyGlaze:
        return updateWhen ( donut => donut.id === action.donutId )
                          , { glaze: action.glaze }
                          , donuts
                          )
      // ...
      default:
        return donuts
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, this is a great example of a purely functional approach to the problem! Love all the function composition and the final syntax of the updateWhen function is just perfect!

Comment: I think this should be somewhere on npm, as I'm sure I'm not the only one to have this problem. If we can hide the behind-the-scenes complexity in a packet just exposing the updateWhen function that would be super useful!

Comment: would you be interested in publishing such package yourself? Otherwise I'd love to do it myself, with all the credit due of course.

Comment: Gavino, your enthusiasm makes me smile. If you do create such a package, please do share the link – Worth noting: `updateWhen` is just *one* useful application of transducers. Transducers could be used to write *all sorts* of useful data transformations in your program. But there is yet another layer of abstraction that is a better data type itself; In this program, our building blocks are `[]` and `{}` and we have to think about transforming them using map and reduce – and now these "transducers" – a better building block would free us from thinking about map/reduce/transduce altogether

Comment: This is where things like native [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and libraries [mori](https://github.com/swannodette/mori)
 and [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) come to play – functional programmers know that `[]` and `{}` just don't cut it in certain circumstances

Comment: But! – transducers are useful for more than abstracting data structures... so a generic transducer library could still be useful. I'd be surprised if one doesn't already exist. If you're interested in learning about the awesome power of transducers, I have some [other answers containing transducer examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transducers) – I owe my understanding of the subject matter to [my role model](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4)